# Octree Change detection initializer but incomplete type error

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am going through the PCL library for a robotics project of mine. I am trying this Octree Change detection program [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/octree_change.php). I am using PCL1.7. I follow the tutorial and when I compile the code I get this error

```
error: variable ‘pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudChangeDetector<pcl::PointXYZ> octree’ has initializer but incomplete type
       pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudChangeDetector<pcl::PointXYZ> octree (resolution);

                                                                                ^
```

Because of this I am getting other errors like

```
‘Octree2BufBase’ was not declared in this scope
         LeafContainerT, BranchContainerT, Octree2BufBase<LeafContainerT, Branch

wrong number of template arguments (5, should be at least 1)
 ontainerT, BranchContainerT, Octree2BufBase<LeafContainerT, BranchContainerT> >       

                                                                      ^

 expected ‘{’ before ‘>’ token
 ontainerT, BranchContainerT, Octree2BufBase<LeafContainerT, BranchContainerT> >
                                                                               ^

expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2564

This is an error in "octree_pointcloud_changedetector.h", u have to add #include "octree2buf_base.h" in this file.